# How to ssh my desktop(ubuntu) from outside network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, nat

I have set up simple ssh server by using openssh on my Ubuntu.

I tried to ssh it from my Mac, which successful. But my mac is in the same subnet, which behind same router at my home.  my ubunut local ip is 192.168.1.***
My outgoing ip is 71.**.**.***

Now, I want be able to ssh my desktop even from my friend's home.

What should I do?

Obviuosly, by doing ssh username@71.**.**.*** wont work. Since there are 3,4 computers are using the same ip behind my route.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a kludge called NAT to connect multiple computers behind a single IP. This prevents you from selecting a specific computer in your local network when you connect from the outside (since you only have a single IP to select).

However if you have control over your firewall (cq the firewall in your router/gateway/modem/switch combination) then you can use **port forwarding**. Basically telling it to forward all incoming connection to 71.x.x.x port 22 to the local computer with ip 192.168.1.x port 22.

Note that you can only do this for a single computer and that you want that computer to have a fixed IP (e.g. make a reservation for that MAC in the DHCP server, or configure a static IP). Otherwise you will need to change the firewall rules every time your servers gets a new IP.